# Get Objfrom List<Obj> given an id without having to iterate through the whole List

Tags: java, list, search, hashmap

I did a bit of investigating before posting this and found that the best way to find the data i need without having to iterate through a whole List is with a HashMap. Now I've never had to use HashMaps before and it's complicating me a lot.

Given this Client class

```
public class Client {
private String nroClient;
private String typeDoc;}
```

I gotta get a typeDoc given an unique nroClient

I've gotten this far

```
    private String getTypeDoc(List<Client> clients, String nroClient) {

    Map <String, Client> map = new HashMap<String, Client>();
    for (Client client : clients) 
    {
        map.put(client.getNroClient(), client);
    }
}
```

It just doesn't seem right at all, and I have no idea how to advance. I'd really appreciate any input. Sorry if this has been asked before, i really tried to find a solution before posting. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've basically got it, but *building* the map is obviously as slow (even slower, in fact) vs. just looping the list.

Given a j.u.List instance, you CANNOT answer the question 'get me the class in this list with ID x, and do it fast'.

The solution is to remove the list entirely and have that be a map.

If you ALSO need list-like aspects (For example, you need to be able to answer the question 'get me the 18th client'), you can either use `LinkedHashMap` which remembers the order in which you added things, but it still doesn't have something like a .get(18) method. If need be you can have a class to represent the notion of 'Clients', internally it has BOTH a list *and* a map, it has an add method that adds your client to both data structures, and now you can answer both 'get me the 18th client' and 'get me the client with this ID' quickly.

Comment: Really helped me, it was building the hashmap on the method that was bothering me rather than bringing a hashmap as parameter. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to return the match?:

```
private String getTypeDoc(List<Client> clients, String nroClient) 
{
    String typeDocFound = null;
    for (Client client : clients) 
    {
        if(client.getNroClient().equals(nroClient)
        {
            typeDocFound = client.getTypeDoc();
            break;
        }
    }
    return typeDocFound;
}
```

Comment: well, it works and it's faster than building a HashMap